# C# Linq query to select top result where a condition is satisfied

Tags: c#, linq

Excuse my English but I will explain what I am trying to achieve. The title may be vague.

I am developing a Payroll program and needed to query a monthly table in order to select a month for which to process using linq. It is for a SAP Business 1 add-on.

**My monthly table (shortened)**

```
Code    U_Month    U_Pay_Process_Status
1       Jan        Y
2       Feb        Y
3       March      Y
4       April      N
5       May        N
6       June       N
7       July       N
8       Aug        N
9       Sept       N
10      Oct        N
11      Nov        N
12      Dec        N
```

Once a payroll month has been processed, e.g. January, the U_Pay_Process_Status field for that month is changed to Y (Yes)

For the above table, how would I write a linq to sql query to select the first unprocessed month (in this case April)?

**I have this so far**

Code is an automatically generated Primary Key in SAP and it is of type varchar.

```
// Get service instance needed
var monthlyPeriodService = Program.Kernel.Get<IMonthlyPeriodService>();

//Query database monthly periods
var monthlyPeriods = monthlyPeriodService.GetAllMonthlyPeriods().OrderBy(m => m.Code);

To do.......
```

How do I get the first unprocessed month. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like:

```
var firstUnprocessed = monthlyPeriodService.GetAllMonthlyPeriods()
                                           .Where(m => !m.Processed)
                                           .OrderBy(m => m.Code)
                                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that this will return null if all periods have been processed (that's what the `OrDefault` bit does for you).

Alternatively:

```
var firstUnprocessed = monthlyPeriodService.GetAllMonthlyPeriods()
                                           .OrderBy(m => m.Code)
                                           .FirstOrDefault(m => !m.Processed);
```

The former version filters out the processed items *before* ordering the results; this will make it more efficient (although whether the efficiency is *significant* or not is another matter) if the query is performed in-process; if this is using a LINQ provider which is converting the query to SQL or something similar, it's unlikely to matter.

Comment: Thanks again Jon Skeet. Can't I just use .FirstOrDefault(m => m.U_Pay_Process_Status == "N"); to get the result?

Comment: only if you can be sure the months are ordered already, FirstOrDefault will return the first unprocessed month it comes to, which - if your database is unordered - might not necessarily be the one you want. If your data already is ordered, then ordering it again is relatively cheap, so why not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following method

```
monthlyPeriods.FirstOrDefault()
```